# Prevent duplicate replies in telethon

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I have this code, which works fine in autoreplying to everyone who sends me a message:

```
message = "hello!"
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, pattern=r'(?i).*hi'))
    async def handle_new_message(event):
        if event.is_private:  # only auto-reply to private chats
            sender = await event.get_sender()  # this lookup will be cached by telethon
            print(time.asctime(), '-', event.message)  # optionally log time and message
            time.sleep(420)  # pause for 1 second to rate-limit automatic replies
            await event.respond(message)
            
            
    print(time.asctime(), '-', 'Auto-replying...')
    client.start(phone, password)
    client.run_until_disconnected()
    print(time.asctime(), '-', 'Stopped!')
```

But i want to limit the reply to only ONCE.
Is there any way to do it?

Im using session files stored in /tmp.

Comment: You'll need to remember who you've send the message to. Database for example. Or in case of a bot and private chat, thats were the /start command is for.